# In Python Pandas DataFrames with column of unique row IDs, how to find column value given row ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Pandas and DataFrames. I have hacked out a solution to my issue, but it is convoluted, so I think I might have done it "wrong".

Let be given a DataFrame with a column that has a unique ID for each row, like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['ID1','ID2','ID3'], 'col': ['a','b','a']})
```

**How do I look up the `col` value of the row with `ID1`, using the `id` value, not the index?**

I know I can do `df1.loc[df1.id == 'ID1'].col.item()` to obtain the same as using the index `df1.col.iloc[0]`, but it just seems convoluted.

Is it the right approach or does there exist a simpler / more recommended way of obtaining the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is perfectly fine. However, since the `id` values are unique, you may want to consider making them the index themselves. Then you would have a shorter way to look up the values:

```py
df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df1.col['ID1']
```

```
'a'
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I did not know this was a possibility! It thought the indexes were immutable.